# Simple solution for jQuery in GET form

Tags: jquery

im trying to prevent empty fields from submitting in search form, form. I found a nice solution and it works, but i don't know jQuery a lot so the code looks very ugly. Can any one recommend better solution?

This is the form JS:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#form1").submit(function() {
            if($("#form-make").val()=="") {
                $("#form-make").prop('disabled', true);
            }
        });
    });
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form1").submit(function() {
        if($("#form-model").val()=="") {
            $("#form-model").prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form1").submit(function() {
        if($("#form-score_start").val()=="") {
            $("#form-score_start").prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form1").submit(function() {
        if($("#form-score_end").val()=="") {
            $("#form-score_end").prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<form method="GET" action="/lots" id="form1">
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
  <div>
      <select name="make" class="form-control" id="form-make">
          <option value="" selected='false'>Select Make</option>
          @foreach($companies as $company)
          <option value="{{ $company->name }}">{{ $company->name }}</option>
          @endforeach
      </select>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>
      <select name="model" class="form-control" id="form-model">
          <option value="" selected='false'>Select Model</option>
          @foreach($models as $model)
              <option value="{{ $model->name }}">{{ $model->name }}</option>
          @endforeach
      </select>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>
      Condition:
      <select name="score_start" id="form-score_start">
      <option value=""selected="TRUE">select</option>
      <option value="3.5">3.5</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="4.5">4.5</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
  </select>
  to
  <select name="score_end" id="form-score_end">
      <option value=""selected="TRUE">select</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="3.5">3.5</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="4.5">4.5</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
  </select>
 </form>
```

Comment: did you give a look at this https://jqueryvalidation.org/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily trim down that code by combining a bunch of repetitive elements.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form1").submit(function() {
        if($("#form-make").val()=="") {
            $("#form-make").prop('disabled', true);
        }
        if($("#form-model").val()=="") {
            $("#form-model").prop('disabled', true);
        }
        if($("#form-score_start").val()=="") {
            $("#form-score_start").prop('disabled', true);
        }
        if($("#form-score_end").val()=="") {
            $("#form-score_end").prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
});
```

To further optimize, you could put the elements you are checking in an array, and loop over them.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form1").submit(function() {
        var objects = ["make", "model", "score_start", "score_end"];
        for (x in objects) {
            var objectID = '#form-'+ x;
            if($(objectID).val()=="") {
                $(objectID).prop('disabled', true);
            }
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: the PHPStorm says there is a mistake in this part: for (int x=0; x < objects.length; x++)

Comment: Sorry, of course the "int" doesn't belong there. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I've actually further simplified it. You can just use "for(x in objects)". And then in the next line just use "+ x" instead of "+ objects[x]"

Answer (score 0):

Serialize the form values, check the value foreach field, if any error then stop the submit else submit it!

That would be the usecase.

Make sure you name every inputfield!
It can be achieved with `serializeArray()` like this:

```
    var $form = $(form).serializeArray();
    var $errors = 0;
    $.each($form, function(i, field) {
        $("*[name="+field.name+"]").removeClass("error");
        var $val = $.trim(field.value);
        if($val == "") {
            $("*[name="+field.name+"]").addClass("error");
            $errors++;
        }
    });
```

See [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/surudoiryu/vxmqehs9/) for a working Demo

Comment: the idea that i have more than 20 parameters in this form and i don't want a huge script in the bottom of the document. ' foreach ' sounds good, can you show? im not very good at jQuery ...

Comment: I will put together something, give me a hour or so need to go home first ;)

Comment: No problem, if you like this solution more then the accepted awnser please upvote for other people reading this post. Thanks!